# Create new variable in from subset of existing columns and if value present create duplicate rows in R

Tags: r

I have a list of columns where three of them relate to year, which identifies the occurrence of that data being collected for that year (1 or -1 means to be collected).  I would like to create / manipulate the dataframe to have 'Year' as a new variable, which would replicate the other columns if it is to be collected for multiple years. What is the most efficient way to do this using dplyr / tidyverse?

I am aware of perhaps using pivot_longer but I assume I made need also to use case_when or similar. Any help appreciated.

```
Programme <- c(1, 2, 2, 3, 4)
Function <- c("Inv", "Inv", "Mac", "Inv", "Inv")
Year2020 <- c(1, 1, 1, -1, 1)
Year2021 <- c(1, 1, *NA*, *NA*, *NA*)
Year2022 <- c(*NA*, *NA*, *NA*, -1, -1)

df <- data.frame(Programme, Function, Year2020, Year2021, Year2022)
```

[image]

So what I am trying to produce is this:

```
Year <- c(2020, 2021, 2020, 2021, 2020, 2020, 2022, 2020, 2022)
Programme <- c(1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4)
Function <- c("Inv", "Inv", "Inv", "Inv", "Mac", "Inv", "Inv", "Inv", "Inv")

df <- data.frame(Year, Programme, Function)
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update** see comments Darren Tsai:"Adding `names_transform = list(Year = parse_number)` into `pivot_longer()` can save you the `mutate` line. Besides, in `tidyr` there is a more flexible function than `na.omit()` to treat NA, i.e. `drop_na()`"

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  pivot_longer(
    cols = starts_with("Year"),
    names_to = "Year",
    names_transform = list(Year = parse_number)
  ) %>% 
  drop_na() %>% 
  dplyr::select(Year, Programme, Function)
```

Alternative pivot method using `names_pattern` and regex `"(\\D+)(\\d+)"`:

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  pivot_longer(
    cols = starts_with("Year"),
    names_to = c(".value", "Year1"),
    names_pattern = "(\\D+)(\\d+)"
  ) %>% 
  na.omit() %>% 
  dplyr::select(Year = Year1, Programme, Function)
```

OR using `parse_number` from `readr` package:

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  pivot_longer(
    cols = starts_with("Year"),
    names_to = "Year"
  ) %>% 
  mutate(Year = parse_number(Year)) %>% 
  na.omit() %>% 
  dplyr::select(Year, Programme, Function)
```

```
  Year  Programme Function
  <chr>     <dbl> <chr>   
1 2020          1 Inv     
2 2021          1 Inv     
3 2020          2 Inv     
4 2021          2 Inv     
5 2020          2 Mac     
6 2020          3 Inv     
7 2022          3 Inv     
8 2020          4 Inv     
9 2022          4 Inv
```

Comment: Adding `names_transform = list(Year = parse_number)` into `pivot_longer()` can save you the `mutate` line. Besides, in `tidyr` there is a more flexible function than `na.omit()` to treat `NA`, i.e. `drop_na()`.

Comment: @Darren Tsai. This is fantastic reminder. Thank you. My actual problem is the latter the arguments the more difficult to remember them for me! :-) I will update!

Answer (score 3):

Using `dplyr`, `tidyr` and `stringr` packages:

```
library(tidyverse)
df |> 
  pivot_longer(3:5,
               names_to = "Year") |> 
  filter(value == 1 | value == -1) |> 
  mutate(Year = str_remove(Year,"^Year")) |> 
  select(Year, Programme, Function)
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 9 x 3
  Year  Programme Function
  <chr>     <dbl> <chr>   
1 2020          1 Inv     
2 2021          1 Inv     
3 2020          2 Inv     
4 2021          2 Inv     
5 2020          2 Mac     
6 2020          3 Inv     
7 2022          3 Inv     
8 2020          4 Inv     
9 2022          4 Inv
```

Comment: Adding `names_prefix = "Year"` into `pivot_longer` can save you the use of `str_remove`. `filter(value %in% c(-1, 1))` and `select(-value)` might be more concise.